# running python code in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

i have some python code(some functions) and i want to implement this in bigger matlab program!how can i do this?any help will be useful....

Comment: hmm seems to be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab

Comment: You might consider translating your Python functions into Matlab and avoid inter-language issues.  Do some rough cost-benefit analysis and decide.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably avoid this. Use one or the other - preferably Python.
But if you have to use both, you could try this:

http://github.com/kw/pymex (scroll down for the readme)

Disclaimer: I wrote this. It may be somewhat difficult to get it to compile and work, particularly if you're on Windows (there is a pre-compiled win32 binary in the downloads area that might work). I don't have access to a lot of different machines with Matlab on them, so I haven't got that nailed down yet.

Comment: Thanks for releasing this code. I am trying to call cython functions from Matlab and had no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [system](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) command to execute the Python code externally. To link it in more "natively" I think you'll have to go through C. That is, embed your Python code in C code and then expose it with a DLL to Matlab.

P.S. On windows you can also expose Python code to Matlab via COM

Comment: @sasha: component object model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of is pythoncall but it is a little out of date and I'm not sure it will work reliably with recent versions of matlab.

http://www.elisanet.fi/ptvirtan/software/pythoncall/index.html

Otherwise you would have to interact with matlab through the shell (a bit of a pain I know). If you are dealing with large amounts of data and are on an OS where you can easily create a ramdisk saving matlab files to a ramdisk and passing the filename would be one way to get data from matlab to python without too much of a performance penalty.

Answer (score -2):

There is a library called [PyMat](http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/Python/pymat.html). It allows to call python code from matlab.

Comment: I didn't use it, so I don't know its limitations.