# How to call python from matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

Can I have both perl.m and python.m so that I can call either perl or python from matlab?
Without knowing exactly how the original perl.m works, I do not feel comfortable simply to replace "perl" with "python". Please help.

Comment: upvote? ... ah, woe to the Electorate badge ;-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call python function from MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Python function from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you have a file `perl.m` used to invoke Perl scripts from Matlab? Of course you can't just change its name to `python.m` and expect it to run Python!

You *have* to look inside `perl.m` to see exactly what it does.

Alternatively, Google on calling Python from Matlab - [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab) and many other useful resources immediately come up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method:

```
status = dos(command)
```

where in 'command' You enter command like in terminal:

for example:

*file - hw.py*

```
print("Hello world")
```

*matlab console:*

```
dos('python yourDir\hw.py')
```

output in terminal:

```
Hello world
```