# Calling Python function from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Call Python function from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780)

I need to call a Python function from a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) environment. Is it possible?

Let's assume, I have the following Python code:

```
def squared(x):
    y = x * x
    return y
```

How do I call squared(3) from MATLAB workspace/code and get 9?

Comment: Adrian suggested a method in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab.                                                                I tried it. I generated a squared.py code, saved it in C:\New, opened the perl.m file, replaced the word perl by python in the code, changed its name to python.m and saved it in C:\New. Matlab shows me the error command:

??? Error using ==> python at 82 System error: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Command executed: python squared.py 2

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this before, so someone else will have to provide a 'real' answer, but
I can offer this.

I often call the shell from MATLAB on my Linux machine, with an exclamation point,  >>!{comm}
So I suppose you could have a shell script that calls python and call the script from MATLAB.

wbg

Comment: Just tried this and I can confirm it works.  If you want to store the result in a variable, use something like x = evalc('!python hello.py')... You may have to specify a path for python since you're on a PC, not sure.

Comment: cool...never used evalc(), will look it up. I would put an in-line python function in () ?

Comment: I hadn't used it either, just looked it up to see how I could return arguments from the command line... I'm not sure what you mean by 'I would put an in-line function in ()'?

Comment: Hello wbg and Jeff, Thanks for your replies. Unfortunately, I still get error messages :S. I guess that I am making mistakes in providing path name. Can you be provide a more detailed description? If I save the squared function, i.e., the program written in the original post, in a code named squared.py, how can I call it from Matlab workspace?

Comment: @Nazmul I'm not sure, it works with just 'python' on a mac, but on a PC it's probably something like !c:\location\of\python.exe squared.py...  Google ! for matlab

Comment: I got it working! I saved the program in C:\Python27. I just added it in the python.m program. Thanks a lot to both of you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: great news....i was about to say, maybe the ! doesn't work on PC's....Consider learning Linux someday, I think it makes numerical programs easier. However, i realize that most work places use windows.