# Call Python function from MATLAB With two or more output arguments

Tags: python, matlab, language-interoperability

I am having problems [calling a Python function in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab).
The question has already been answered on this website, [Call python function from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab), But solutions are not usable for me.

The topics presented above are several ways to use Python scripts in Matlab there.
But I need to find a way to have multiple output arguments from a Python script I get in MATLAB.

this way :

```
system('python pythonfile.py argument')
system('python test.py 2')
```

and

```
>> r=python('sqd.py','3.5')
r =
12.25
>> r=python('sqd.py','5')
r =
25.0
>>
```

The above methods
Not Able to two or more arguments of the data returned into Matlab! 
I want to get a few arguments in MATLAB. 
I am looking for a simple way similar to the above or easy way!

**What's the solution for this?**

Sorry for my poor English.I'm German.

Comment: How are you trying to call python + args in Matlab?

Comment: I could not succeed up with ways to get multiple output parameters.
For example:
      
>> [a b]=python('sample.py','2' '3' '5')

Comment: Try the `pythoncall` project: https://github.com/pv/pythoncall

Comment: Thanks rayseng. But pythoncall on MATLAB 2014 problem. Whether you used and executed? How to?

Comment: @Pepe - I apologize.  I should have looked at the documentation before writing a comment.  `pythoncall` doesn't work for newer versions of MATLAB.

Comment: @Pepe - Are you using MATLAB 2014? Which version? R2014a or R2014b?  MATLAB has Python support within the environment.  You have the ability to call Python functions directly without using `system`.

Comment: @rayryeng -  I am using the R2014b version, but if need be I can use the R2014a version. Or newer.
How to? Help me please