# Output not shown while running a python code in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I have used the thread 
[Call Python function from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab) 
and have implemented it successfully in Matlab.

However, the following code in python reflects no output in Matlab, and due to my lack of familiarity with Python, I can't see where the problem may originate from!

So here is the python code which takes a graph as input like :

```
bipartiteMatch({0:[0,1,3],1:[3,4],2:[1,2,4],3:[2,3,4],4:[0,2,3]})
```

and gives the set of maximum matchings in the form above,

```
# Hopcroft-Karp bipartite max-cardinality matching and max independent set
# David Eppstein, UC Irvine, 27 Apr 2002
#import sys
def bipartiteMatch(graph):
'''Find maximum cardinality matching of a bipartite graph (U,V,E).
The input format is a dictionary mapping members of U to a list
of their neighbors in V.  The output is a triple (M,A,B) where M is a
dictionary mapping members of V to their matches in U, A is the part
of the maximum independent set in U, and B is the part of the MIS in V.
The same object may occur in both U and V, and is treated as two
distinct vertices if this happens.'''

# initialize greedy matching (redundant, but faster than full search)
matching = {}
for u in graph:
    for v in graph[u]:
        if v not in matching:
            matching[v] = u
            break

while 1:
    # structure residual graph into layers
    # pred[u] gives the neighbor in the previous layer for u in U
    # preds[v] gives a list of neighbors in the previous layer for v in V
    # unmatched gives a list of unmatched vertices in final layer of V,
    # and is also used as a flag value for pred[u] when u is in the first       layer
    preds = {}
    unmatched = []
    pred = dict([(u,unmatched) for u in graph])
    for v in matching:
        del pred[matching[v]]
    layer = list(pred)

    # repeatedly extend layering structure by another pair of layers
    while layer and not unmatched:
        newLayer = {}
        for u in layer:
            for v in graph[u]:
                if v not in preds:
                    newLayer.setdefault(v,[]).append(u)
        layer = []
        for v in newLayer:
            preds[v] = newLayer[v]
            if v in matching:
                layer.append(matching[v])
                pred[matching[v]] = v
            else:
                unmatched.append(v)

    # did we finish layering without finding any alternating paths?
    if not unmatched:
        unlayered = {}
        for u in graph:
            for v in graph[u]:
                if v not in preds:
                    unlayered[v] = None
        return (matching,list(pred),list(unlayered))

    # recursively search backward through layers to find alternating paths
    # recursion returns true if found path, false otherwise
    def recurse(v):
        if v in preds:
            L = preds[v]
            del preds[v]
            for u in L:
                if u in pred:
                    pu = pred[u]
                    del pred[u]
                    if pu is unmatched or recurse(pu):
                        matching[v] = u
                        return 1
        return 0

    for v in unmatched: recurse(v)
```

I can see the output and run the code in python successfully, but the output is not shown in Matlab and returns `" "` as the answer.

So any kind of help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: there is not return statement at the bottom of the function, if it reaches the end without hitting a return statement it implicitly returns `None` (which I assume matlab converts to " ")

Comment: you may want either `return all(recurse(v) for v in unmatched)` or similarly with `any` to return a boolean, but based on the other return statement you have I'm not sure a boolean is the desired result...

Comment: thanks for the comment; but unfortunately this does not seem to work ...

Comment: What are you expecting to return to matlab? After looking at the other thread it looks like it doesn't call any functions but treats the script as the system call - which means you need to use `sys.argv` for the arguments passed from matlab and write to `sys.stdout` (by printing) to return stuff to matlab.  Since you do neither your script is really only defining a function the quitting.