# Returning values from Python function running in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I am testing calling Python functions through MATLAB, but I am not getting what I expected. I figured I could call a Python function within MATLAB and have whatever that function returns, given to a MATLAB variable, as follows:

Python script (saved as test_for_mlab.py):

```
def out_func(arg_1):
    print 'This print statement is in Python'
    a = int(arg_1 * 10)
    return a
```

MATLAB part:

```
val = py.test_for_mlab.out_func(33);
```

I was expecting val to have a value of 330 (int). Instead, the message I get in MATLAB is val = Python NoneType with no properties. None.

How can I get my desired results?

Comment: It might help to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab

Comment: I get a `Python int with properties: ...` which has value 330, as expected. Using MATLAB R2017a and Python 3.6 from Anaconda.

Comment: @hbaderts Maybe it doesnt work for me because I am using Python 2.7. Strange that I am able to get print outputs into MATLAB but not return variables.

Answer (score 0):

My latest tests in Matlab 2022 suggest that the return of values only works with scripts but not with functions.
A workaround is to write a simple wrapper script in Python, like so:

return_script.py:

```
 from return_value_test import main
 import sys
 a = main(sys.argv)
```

return_value_test.py:

```
 import sys
 
 def main(argv):
     print(argv)
     x = int(argv[1])
     a = x
     b = a + 1

     return b

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(sys.argv[1:])
```

How to call the script from Matlab with a command line parameter of 2,  the return value of a should be 3 (original a + 1):

`a = pyrunfile("return_script.py 2", "a")`