# Call Python from Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, interop

I need to call these Python functions from Matlab. something like this:

```
  matplotlib.pyplot 
  matplotlib 
  numpy
```

But I don't know how to begin with. e.g., I installed Python on my computer but didn't help etc ... I need to learn it from scratch
I also look at below link but didn't help :(
[Call Python function from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab)

Comment: For starting out, it will be much easier to learn Python without having the extra layer of trying to use it from within MATLAB. I would learn some Python first, before you start mixing the two. You might even find you don't need MATLAB any more...

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. It is also not a site to help you search for documentation. When you have done your research and made a specific attempt, we might be able to help, as long as you follow the rules in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open Matlab **from the terminal:**

Go to the bin:

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/bin/
```

Open it:

```
./matlab
```

Next, to use Python type:

```
!python
```

**This answer assumes that you have already installed Python on your system.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I designed a MATLAB controller for some hardware but the scripts to control the hardware were written in Python.

As an example, I have a python script in the same working directory called test.py

```
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

In MATLAB, I can run this script using the command: `py.test.hello`

[Image of my MATLAB command window output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXDo.png)

It returns a friendly message :)