# Is MATLAB able to communicate with Unix Domain Sockets?

Tags: matlab, unix-socket

Can MATLAB communicate with Unix Domain Sockets?

I'm able to use the function `tcpconnect` over a TCP/IP Socket but it seems impossible with an UDS.

Is there a solution to achieve this?

Comment: What is the code you try to run?

Comment: I'm trying to run that kind of code : ``tcpconnect("/path/to/uds", random_port)`` but obviously it won't work using this command since it is designed for TCP. Maybe the only way is to use a C script doing UDS Client but I'm trying to avoid this :)

Comment: I guess the answer to your first question is no. Primary option I see is using a python implementation which can be used in MATLAB ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189167/2732801 ). For performance critical applications I would consider writing a c mex function instead, but that is probably also more work.