# Run Boto3 example in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, boto3

is there a way to execute the simple table creation request example in matlab by using the python functions in matlab?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html

Thank you in advance,
Leo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you taken the [tour] yet? A well-asked question (read [ask]) should include what you found [from your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) prior to asking here.